# Rearrange excel table cells - reordering

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I don't know excel very well and I am trying to take something like this (with a lot of entries):

Field    ......Value     .......  ID

A       .......... blabla1  .......1

B        ...........blabla2 .......1

C        ...........blabla3 .......1

D        ...........blabla4 .......1

A        ...........blabla5 .......2

B       ...........blabla6  .......2

C        ...........blabla7 .......2

D        ...........blabla8 .......2

and turn into something more readable like this:

ID -----A      -------------B    ----------------   C    ----------------   D

1   ------blabla1   -----blabla2  --------  blabla3 --------blabla4

2   ------blabla5-----  blabla6 -------- blabla7--------    blabla8

Does anyone know a good way to do that? Thank you
(sorry about the bad formatting)

Comment: tried that, but then the fields order became: A B C D A B C D repeated and the IDs went to the line below, not to the front.

Comment: It's going to be a lot, a couple hundred rows :(

Comment: I GOT IT by using this: https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/

Comment: Just deleted my irrelevant comments and wanted to mention; to someone who says they don't know Excel very well, and then uses Index-matching-multiple-criteria!.... Bravo!!

Comment: Darn - next time I'll make sure to read all comments before spending time on a solution - looks like already solved before I even started :(

Answer (score 0):

The exact [delimiter](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delimiter) beween each word is key if text not already split in separate cells..

Assuming there are numerous words in place of '.....', with each word separated by a single space (different delimiter would be required if the *blablas* represented sentences comprising one / more spaces), then you could achieve the desired table representation as follows

*(several function in this soln requires Office 365 compatible version of Excel,
the lookup in step 3 does not require Office 365, but may mean IDs and Fields need to be manually entered or VB could be deployed):*

**Starting position (after removing bank rows):**

| Field Value ID |
| --- |
| A blabla1 1 |
| B blabla2 1 |
| C blabla3 1 |
| D blabla4 1 |
| A blabla5 2 |
| B blabla6 2 |
| C blabla7 2 |
| D blabla8 2 |

---

**1) Split cells according to delimiter  (skip this step if not relevant)**

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<x><y>"&SUBSTITUTE(F3," ","</y><y>")&"</y></x>","//y"))
```

[image: Filterxml function (depending on delimiter)]

*(replace the " " inside the substitute function with a different delimiter if required/desired)*

---

**2) Obtain unique IDs (rows) and Fields (columns)**

```
=UNIQUE(K4:K11)
```

[image: IDs]

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(I4:I11))
```

[image: Fields]

---

**3) Index lookup for table content**

```
=INDEX(J4:J11,MATCH(M4#&N3#,K4:K11&I4:I11,0),0)
```

[image: Index lookup]